# why (') append with number in excel-export plugin use in grails

Tags: grails

when I used excel-export:0.2.1 plug-in use in Grails but problem is that its append (') star with number
like '08:00:00 Pm shows in excel formula bar,how to fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

Convert the property to a String.  You can use a formatter closure supported by the plugin.

```
def title = { domain, value ->
               return value.toString()
            }
```

Comment: Sorry! what you want to say?